# Convert date in file from yyyyMMdd to store in SQL as MMddYYYY

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a file with dates in this format: 20150530. I need to format them into the following format: 05302015 before inserting them into a SQL table.  My original code was:

```
private string NormalizeDate(string strInput)
    {
        string strOutput;
        DateTime date;


        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strInput, "YYYYMMdd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            strOutput = date.ToString("MMddYYYY");
            return strOutput.Trim();
        }
        else
        {

            return strInput.Trim();
        }
    }
```

However, the format of the date is not changing before I insert into SQL.  I wanted the date to be in the format of MMddYYYY (with no dashes or spaces) when I insert into my table.  Then with that format I need to merge those dates into a different table but the format needs to be MMddYYYY.

The only other option I would have is to have some kind of query that can take the original date from lets say Table1 (20150530) and then convert the format to Table2 in the format of (05302015).  I am trying not to confuse anyone.  The data type of Table1 is datetime and the column it will be inserted into Table2 is nvarchar.

Comment: what type is the column? if its a date then formatting shouldn't matter.

Comment: ...and if its not a date then why isn't it a date? :) But seriously, what have you tried so far? Where are you having problems?

Comment: It is datetime.  I need this format to change for a specific and unique reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JustinSmith if it's a datetime, SQL would prefer you to pass it as: `20100530` - `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Are you inserting via `BULK` or regular  `INSERT` commands?

Comment: This betrays a mis-understanding of how Sql Server handles DateTime columns. Sql Server stores _all_ DateTime columns using a binary format this is **not human readable**. Anything else you see either isn't really a DateTime column (in which case, what were you thinking!?) or is just shown a convenience by your query tool.

Answer (score 0):

if it is stored as datetime then

```
declare @time date ='20100530'

select
replace(convert(varchar, @time, 101),'/','')
```

if it is stored as an int then

```
declare @time int ='20100530'

select
replace(convert(varchar, cast(CONVERT(varchar, @time)as DATE),101),'/','')
```

both will change it to 05302010

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about format at all when talking between C# and Sql Server, you've already lost. Caring about format implies you're using techniques that are **horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks!**

Instead of something like this:

```
//Don't **EVER** put data into SQL strings this, or I will hunt you down and kill your dog.
string sql = "INSERT INTO [table] (column1, column2) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')";
foreach (var values in data)
{
    sqlcmd.CommandText = string.Format(sql, values[0], NormalizeDate(values[1]));
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You need to do it like this:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table] (column1, column2) VALUES (@column1, @column2)";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@column1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@column2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
foreach (var values in data)
{
    sqlcmd.Parameters["@column1"].Value = values[0];
    sqlcmd.Parameters["@column2"].Value = DateTime.Parse(values[1]);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The point here is that you use a C# datetime type to talk with a Sql Server Datetime column, and that you use **Parameterized Queries** to make this happen.

When you do this, **you don't care about format any more**. It's all handled for you behind the scenes by ADO.Net. Additionally, this is the only fail-safe way to be sure you're code is not crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Now, it's almost certainly the case that, after all of this, Sql Server is not storing the datetime column using the format you expect. In fact, Sql Server using a binary format for datetime values that is *not even human-readable*. The format you're used to seeing with SQL is just something that the query tools show for convenience. And that's *okay*, because it works the same way coming out again. When you retrieve data back from the database, ADO.Net will do it's thing again, you get a .Net DateTime value, and you can format that to your heart's content.

This is how databases are *supposed* to work: the data at rest in the DB lives in the format that is most efficient for the DB, and it's the job of the query or the application to just-in-time format it for the specific presentation case that you need.